# I want to show images from resources in pictureboxes randomly

Tags: c#, winforms

With a List of 6 images names and a list of six picture boxes, I want to show images from resources in picture boxes randomly.

This code is not working. Just empty picture boxes.... Why?

```
List<PictureBox> box = new List<PictureBox>();
box.Add(pictureBox1);
box.Add(pictureBox2);
box.Add(pictureBox3);
box.Add(pictureBox4);
box.Add(pictureBox5);
box.Add(pictureBox6);

List<string> name = new List<string>();
name.Add("_1.jpg");
name.Add("_2.jpg");
name.Add("_3.jpg");
name.Add("_4.jpg");
name.Add("_5.jpg");
name.Add("_6.jpg");

Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < box.Count; i++)
{
  int rand = r.Next(0, 6);
  String imgname = name[rand];                
  object Ob= Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imgname);
  box[i].Image = Ob as Image;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code:

```
List<PictureBox> box = new List<PictureBox>();
box.AddRange(new PictureBox[]
{
    pictureBox1,
    pictureBox2,
    pictureBox3,
    pictureBox4,
    pictureBox5,
    pictureBox6,
});

List<string> name = new List<string>()
{
    "_1.jpg",
    "_2.jpg",
    "_3.jpg",
    "_4.jpg",
    "_5.jpg",
    "_6.jpg"
};

Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
{
    var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(((System.Reflection.Assembly)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources", ((System.Reflection.Assembly)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    this[i].Image = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(name[r.Next(0, 6)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resources typically do not include the file extension, so try just using the name of the image.

```
name.Add("_1");
name.Add("_2");
```

Personally, I would not include an underscore in the file names — might complicate things.